# ¿Alguien que sepa ocupar @Input y @Output?

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación web que muestra los datos generales del juego Age Of Empires II (civilizaciones, unidades, estructuras y tecnología [API]) . Los datos los muestro con ayuda de MatTable.
El punto es que quiero crear un componente que filtre información de las diferentes tablas... ya que conseguí algo parecido, lo cual era tener el metodo en cada componente uilizado por separado... Pero ahora quiero ocupar @Input y @Output y crear el componente filter. Así tengo la posibilidad de pasarle los datos con @Input y devolver los datos con @Output (lo cual va dentro del componente filter).

**Ejemplo:**

```
<app-search [data]="units" (result)="handleSearchResult($event)"></app-search>
```

Ese $event lo debo manejar en el typescript y lo debo asignar al nuevo array con los datos filtrados.

La verdad he leido varios foros de @Input y @Output, pero todavía no entiendo como ocuparlo en este ejmplo en especifico.
le mostrare la estructura del componente units:

**units.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GameService } from '../../services/game.service';
import { Units } from '../models/units.model';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-units',
  templateUrl: './units.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./units.component.css']
})
export class UnitsComponent implements OnInit {

  private units: Units[] = [];
  private uni: Units;
  public displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'name', 
    'description', 
    'expansion', 
    'age',
    'cost', 
    'build_time',
    'reload_time', 
    'attack_delay', 
    'movement_rate', 
    'line_of_sight', 
    'hit_points',
    'range', 
    'attack', 
    'armor', 
    'accuracy'
  ];
  public dataSource : any;

  constructor(private gameService: GameService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.gameService.getUnits().subscribe(
      res => {
        let x;
        x=res['units'];

        x.forEach(element => {
          this.uni = new Units();
          this.uni.name = element['name'];
          this.uni.description = element['description'];
          this.uni.expansion = element['expansion'];
          this.uni.age = element['age'];
          this.uni.cost = element['cost'];
          this.uni.build_time = element['build_time'];
          this.uni.reload_time = element['reload_time'];
          this.uni.attack_delay = element['attack_delay'];
          this.uni.movement_rate = element['attack_delay'];
          this.uni.line_of_sight = element['line_of_sight'];
          this.uni.hit_points = element['hit_points'];
          this.uni.range = element['range'];
          this.uni.attack = element['attack'];
          this.uni.armor = element['armor'];
          this.uni.accuracy = element['accuracy'];
          this.units.push(this.uni);
        });
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
        this.dataSource.data = this.units;
      },
      err => console.error(err)
    );
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();
  }
}
```

**units.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)"
    placeholder="Filter">
</mat-form-field>
<div class="container mat-elevation-z8">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="table-container">

        <ng-container matColumnDef="name" sticky>
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Nombre </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
        </ng-container> class="mat-elevation-z8"

        <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Descripción </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
                <p> <br/> {{element.description}} </p> 
            </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="expansion">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Expansión </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.expansion}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="age">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Edad </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.age}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="cost">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Costo </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                <p> 
                    <br/> {{'Madera: ' + (element.cost.Wood || '0')}} 
                    <br/> {{'Comida: ' + (element.cost.Food || '0')}} 
                    <br/> {{'Oro: ' + (element.cost.Gold || '0')}}
                    <br/> {{'Info: ' + (element.cost.info || '0')}}
                </p>
            </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="build_time">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Tiempo de Construcción </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.build_time}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="reload_time">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Tiempo de Recarga </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.reload_time}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="attack_delay">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Retraso de Ataque</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.attack_delay}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="movement_rate">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Velocidad de Movimiento </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.movement_rate}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="line_of_sight">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Sitio de la Linea </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.line_of_sight}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="hit_points">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Puntos de Golpe </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.hit_points}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="range">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Rango </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.range}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="attack">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Ataque</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.attack}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="armor">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Armadura </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.armor}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="accuracy">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Exactitud</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.accuracy}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; "></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

EL método applyFilter() funciona correctamente.